# How can I have a dropdown option for user (React-Native App)?

Tags: react-native

I am creating a BMI Calculator in react-native. One of the things I am unable to figure out is how to place a dropdown either within the TextInput field or beside it.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
 import {
   View,
   Text,
   TouchableOpacity,
   TextInput,
   StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

 import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';

 class Inputs extends Component {
    state = {
       height: '',
       weight: '',
       bmi: '',
       BmiResult: '',
    }
    handleHeight = (text) => {
       this.setState({ height: text })
    }
    handleWeight = (text) => {
       this.setState({ weight: text })
    }
    calculate = (height, weight) => {
       //calculation
       var result = (parseFloat(weight)*10000)/(parseFloat(height)*parseFloat(height));
       result = result.toFixed(2);
       //display result
       this.setState({ bmi: result })
       if(result<18.5){
          this.setState({BmiResult:'Underweight'})
       }
       else if(result>=18.5&&result<25){
          this.setState({BmiResult:'Normal weight'})
       }
       else if(result>=25&&result<30){
          this.setState({BmiResult:'Overweight'})
       }
       else if(result>=30){
          this.setState({BmiResult:'Obese'})
       }
       else{
          alert('Incorrect Input!');
          this.setState({BmiResult:''})
       }
    }
    render() {
       return (
          <View style = {styles.container}>
 <Text style={styles.title}>BMI Calculator</Text>


             <Text  style = {styles.label}>Height</Text>
             <TextInput style = {styles.input}
                underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
                placeholder = "Height (Cm)"
                autoCapitalize = "none"
                onChangeText = {this.handleHeight}/>
              //<Text style = {styles.label}>CMS or FT</Text>

              <Text  style = {styles.label}>Weight</Text>
              <TextInput style = {styles.input}
                underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
                placeholder = "Weight (Kg)"
                autoCapitalize = "none"
                onChangeText = {this.handleWeight}/>
              //<Text style = {styles.label}>cms or ft</Text>

             <TouchableOpacity
                style = {styles.submitButton}
                onPress = {
                   () => this.calculate(this.state.height, this.state.weight)
                }>
                <Text style = {styles.submitButtonText}> Calculate </Text>
             </TouchableOpacity>
 <Text style = {styles.output}>{this.state.bmi}</Text>
             <Text style = {styles.resultText}>{this.state.BmiResult}</Text>
 </View>
       )
    }
 }
 export default Inputs
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
       paddingTop: 23,

    },
    input: {
       margin: 15,
       height: 40,
       borderWidth: 1,
       padding: 10,
    },
    submitButton: {
       backgroundColor: '#ff6666',
       padding: 10,
       margin: 15,
       height: 40,
    },
    submitButtonText:{
       textAlign: "center",
       color: 'white',
      // fontWeight:"bold",
       fontSize: 18,
    },
    output:{
       textAlign: "center",
       fontSize: 30,
    },
    title:{
       paddingTop:30,
       paddingBottom:10,
       textAlign: "center",
       fontSize: 30,
       fontWeight:"bold",
    },
    resultText:{
       paddingTop:20,
       paddingBottom:10,
       textAlign: "center",
       fontSize: 30,
       color: 'blue'
    },
    label:{
       marginLeft: 15,
    }
 })
```

Here is a screenshot of the app running:

[Click Here To View Screenshot Of App Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYHYA.png)

I want to add a dropdown where the user can pick either

1. KG or LBS for the weight.
2. CMS or FT for the height.

Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you

```js
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
      View,
      Text,
      TouchableOpacity,
      TextInput,
      StyleSheet,
    } from 'react-native';

    import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';

    class Inputs extends Component {
     state = {
        height: '',
        weight: '',
        bmi: '',
        BmiResult: '',
        heightOpen: false,
        heightValue: null,
        heightItems : [
          {label: 'CMS', value: 'CMS'},
          {label: 'FT', value: 'FT'}
        ],
        weightOpen: false,
        weightValue: null,
        weightItems : [
          {label: 'KG', value: 'KG'},
          {label: 'LBS', value: 'LBS'}
        ]

      };

      setWeightOpen = (weightOpen) => {
        this.setState({
          weightOpen,
          heightOpen: false
        });
      }

      setWeightValue = (callback) => {
        this.setState(state => ({
          weightValue: callback(state.weightValue)
        }));
      }

      setWeightItems = (callback) => {
        this.setState(state => ({
          weightItems: callback(state.weightItems)
        }));
      }

      setHeightOpen = (heightOpen) => {
        this.setState({
          heightOpen,
          weightOpen: false
        });
      }

      setHeightValue = (callback) => {
        this.setState(state => ({
          heightValue: callback(state.heightValue)
        }));
      }

      setHeightItems = (callback) => {
        this.setState(state => ({
          heightItems: callback(state.heightItems)
        }));
      }

      handleHeight = (text) => {
        this.setState({ height: text });
      };
      handleWeight = (text) => {
        this.setState({ weight: text });
      };
      calculate = (height, weight) => {
        //calculation
        var result =
          (parseFloat(weight) * 10000) / (parseFloat(height) * parseFloat(height));
        result = result.toFixed(2);
        //display result
        this.setState({ bmi: result });
        if (result < 18.5) {
          this.setState({ BmiResult: 'Underweight' });
        } else if (result >= 18.5 && result < 25) {
          this.setState({ BmiResult: 'Normal weight' });
        } else if (result >= 25 && result < 30) {
          this.setState({ BmiResult: 'Overweight' });
        } else if (result >= 30) {
          this.setState({ BmiResult: 'Obese' });
        } else {
          alert('Incorrect Input!');
          this.setState({ BmiResult: '' });
        }
      };
      
    render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>BMI Calculator</Text>
            <Text style={styles.label}>Height</Text>
            <DropDownPicker
              placeholder={'Select Height'}
              open={this.state.heightOpen}
              value={this.state.heightValue}
              style={[styles.input, {flexDirection: 'row'}]}
              items={this.state.heightItems}
              setOpen={this.setHeightOpen}
              setValue={this.setHeightValue}
              setItems={this.setHeightItems}
            />

            <TextInput
              disabled={ this.state.heightValue == null ? true : false}
              style={styles.input}
              underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
              placeholder={this.state.weightValue == null ? "Height " : "Height in 
              "+this.state.weightValue}
              autoCapitalize="none"
              onChangeText={this.handleHeight}
            />
            //<Text style={styles.label}>CMS or FT</Text>
            <Text style={styles.label}>Weight</Text>

            <DropDownPicker
              placeholder={'Select Weight'}
              open={this.state.weightOpen}
              value={this.state.weightValue}
              style={[styles.input, {flexDirection: 'row'}]}
              items={this.state.weightItems}
              setOpen={this.setWeightOpen}
              setValue={this.setWeightValue}
              setItems={this.setWeightItems}
            />

            <TextInput
              disabled={ this.state.weightValue == null ? true : false}
              style={styles.input}
              underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
              placeholder={this.state.weightValue == null ? "Weight " : "Weight in 
              "+this.state.weightValue}
              autoCapitalize="none"
              onChangeText={this.handleWeight}
            />
            //<Text style={styles.label}>cms or ft</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.submitButton}
              onPress={() => this.calculate(this.state.height, this.state.weight)}>
                 <Text style={styles.submitButtonText}> Calculate </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={styles.output}>{this.state.bmi}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.resultText}>{this.state.BmiResult}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
    export default Inputs;
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        paddingTop: 23,
      },
      input: {
        margin: 15,
        height: 40,
        borderWidth: 1,
        padding: 10,
      },
      submitButton: {
        backgroundColor: '#ff6666',
        padding: 10,
        margin: 15,
        height: 40,
      },
      submitButtonText: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: 'white',
        // fontWeight:"bold",
        fontSize: 18,
      },
      output: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 30,
      },
      title: {
        paddingTop: 30,
        paddingBottom: 10,
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      },
      resultText: {
        paddingTop: 20,
        paddingBottom: 10,
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 30,
        color: 'blue',
      },
      label: {
        marginLeft: 15,
      },
    });
```

Also, you can add Styling on your own. For better knowledge about the dropdown library check this [link](https://morioh.com/p/21d1673e56fb) out.

Comment: Agreed [react-native-dropdown-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dropdown-picker) might be useful here, but better to add a link to an example :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: is there a way to change the size of the dropdown ?

Comment: Add this prop to `DropDownPicker` like, `containerStyle={{height: any}}` OR change it with the `style` prop of `DropDownPicker` like `style={[styles.input, {flexDirection: 'row', height: any}]}`